# Stream video from drone Parrot 2.0. Python + cv2

Tags: python, opencv, ar.drone

I am trying to have access to the stream of my drone's camera.

Here my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy
import libardrone

drone = libardrone.ARDrone()
cap = drone.image

while(True):
    cap = drone.image
    if not cap:
        continue
    ret, frame = convert
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It does not work. It does not open any frame where I can see the stream video of my drone's camera.
What's wrong? Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('tcp://192.168.1.1:5555')
running = True
while running:
    # get current frame of video
    running, frame = cam.read()
    if running:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27: 
            # escape key pressed
            running = False
    else:
        # error reading frame
        print 'error reading video feed'
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Try this code...This works for me.